# macOS: Is there a way to show an image constantly on screen (like a watermark)?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, screen-capture, quicktime

I'm looking for a very simple way to add a watermark to my screen which should be shown whatever I'm doing, is it during a Zoom call, or is it when giving a presentation, or similar (I don't necessarily need it to show during fullscreen mode).

The reason is that I want to record my screen using QuickTime Player, and the watermark should be on the video. I know that there are many post-production tools that offer adding watermarks, but I don't want to do any post-production, I want to have everything on screen while recording already.

(I also know that there are screen recorders which offer placing a watermark to the end result. I'd rather also avoid using another screen recording software, but if I don't find any other way to do it, then I'm open to a simple, non-pricy alternative to QuickTime Player.)

Comment: So far, I've come to buy and use the app [Iris Screen Recorder](https://staticz.com/iris/) which, in addition to watermarks, offers some more nice features, that QuickTime does not (ie. recording system audio).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/). It allows to combine images, video sources etc into one stream and provides a virtual camera which can then be used as the video source in Zoom.

Comment: Thank you, this is a possible option. I would prefer a simple tool though that puts an image on top of all other window. This would drain less CPU and is easier to set up.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but I suspect you could accomplish this simply by using Photoshop or another page layout app to create an image containing the watermark. Match the document dimensions to your display's native resolution (on MB Pro: 2880 x 1800), then set this new image as your desktop background. You could even use Keynote to make the image, if you change the ruler increments to pixels instead of inches - as I've done here: [image: Example Desktop]

Comment: This doesn't take into account any windows overlapping the desktop, or any mouse hovering over the "watermark".